# File could not be uploaded: missing temporary directory

Tags: php, laravel

I have an issue with image uploading using the Laravel framework.

The Exception message :

> File could not be uploaded: missing temporary directory.

that happens only in the Hosting 000webhost, it works fine in Local.

My local is running on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a configuration problem on your web server.

Check the php.ini file. Check the parameter "upload_tmp_dir " and check path permission. Try to change the setting and give the server appropriate permission.

Comment: I using move() in Laravel, the path:
"/storage/ssd4/760/232131/public_html/hopdong/LightZ Real Estate".

I also set permission 777

Comment: I missing the folder tmp in host, thank u very much :)